# PUBG mobile api - is there any pubg mobile api exists which return user info

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

Our team is going to make a website which provides services of pubg. As you can see this website : `https://www.midasbuy.com/in/buy/pubgm#`. so **Is there any pubg api for mobile exists ? That takes pubg profile id (Player's Id) and returns the user info (Player account info) as name etc.** Profile Id sample is attached. [Image added for profile Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW8wH.jpg)

Comment: I have the Api key from  https://developer.pubg.com/

Comment: PUBG Mobile is developed and maintained by Tencent and they don't have any plan to provide API for PUBG Mobile in the near future.

You can view this thread for more information https://forums.pubg.com/topic/289780-pubg-api-for-mobile/

Answer (score -1):

The PUBG API let's you search by player account ID.

Using `/players/{accountId}`retrieves the player objects contain information about a player and a list of their recent matches (up to 14 days old). Note: player objects are specific to platform shards.

See more in here: https://documentation.pubg.com/en/players-endpoint.html#/

Comment: https://api.pubg.com/shards/{platform}/players/{accountId} 

It needs account Id not the profile ID

Comment: What leads you to believe the number on your photo is the profile ID and not the account ID? I think the number you pointed is the account ID.

Comment: NO, its not the account Id, its the profile ID of User, it is not working for getting the player's info. at /players/{accountId}

Comment: @navdeep maybe the mobile data is not available in the API yet, I would suggest you to send a mail directly to the PUBG Mobile section. Link: https://support.pubg.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002193033-PUBG-Mobile-questions-notices-and-more

Comment: PUBG  and PUBG-MOBILE are two different, and the topic is about PUBG-MOBILE, not PUBG